# How can I get a VB webbrowser control to click a button that cannot be clicked manually in the control but can in an actual IE window?

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I have clicked many buttons without ever hitting a problem like this. I'm using VB 2010. If I click on the control programmatically or manually, the screen flashes like it is just refreshing. However, if I open a separate IE window, I can click the button and it advances to another screen as expected. I have researched this on other sites and have found one suggestion that the control is using a different version than the full version, which is IE 8 in my case. This still doesn't provide a solution. Can anyone please help? Here is the code which clicks the button as well as the html of the button.
    WebBrowser1.Document.All("posForm:estimate").InvokeMember("click")

```
<button onclick="validateForEstimate(this, 'NonITS');" type="button" name="getestiamte"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the Microsoft Browser go to your toolbox right click and click choose items then go to COM components and use the filter to find Microsoft browser then check mark it. Add it to your form and done.

Comment: I have added the component. I will have to change the coding however since this control uses different properties and methods. I think this might work. It may take a couple of days or so to get it re-coded to know for sure.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but I know how you can fix this implement geckofx, openwebkitsharp or awesomium <------ Suggested                            These are web browsers that have added fuctions and better support. Just search awesomium and install it for vb make sure you have .net framework 4.5 or it might fail.

Comment: That is a good suggestion but I have come across another problem. There are certain pages where I need to send keystrokes and program focus is required. This becomes difficult to shuffle because I may need up to 50 instances of the program running at the same time.

Comment: If you can do it with the default IE control the new one show be able to do it too.

Comment: I tried both the webbrowser and Microsoft Browser (axwebbrowser) controls and neither worked. For my purposes now it doesn't matter. The issue of window focus with multiple instances running is a bigger problem now. Thanks.